# Any option to select value in between 2 selected items in Selectzie.js in Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, selectize.js

I am using [`Selectize.js`](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) to an input to choose multiple options. The order of the selected value is important for me and I need an option to change the order of selected values or select a new option in between selected values.

But in mobile view, there seems no option to choose a value between 2 selected values. This works on a desktop by using only arrow keys in the keyboard.

There are plugins available such as `remove_button` and `drag_drop`, but both are helpless in my situation. `drag_drop` plugin is not yet working in the mobile. and `remove_button` only help to unselect a value.

**Steps to reproduce**:

1. On a form with the input of `Selectize` initialized.
2. Select 3 values from the drop-down
3. Try to add an option in between 2 and 3

**Expected Result**:
See a text cursor in the input in between the value 2 and 3 and display the drop-down option to choose. If we choose an option, it will add in between 2 and 3

**Actual Result**:
There we can't see any cursor while clicking in between 2 selected values, only we can click on the selected value which doesn't make any changes.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nishalkr93/fxr8pd1j/) Link is here

```js
var optionList = [{ "name": "radialis",
                      "id": "1"
                  },
                  { "name": "Extensor",
                      "id": "2"
                  },
                  { "name": "Median nerve",
                      "id": "3"
                  },
                  { "name": "syndrome",
                      "id": "4"
                  },
                  { "name": "carpi",
                      "id": "5"
                  },
                  { "name": "longus",
                      "id": "6"
                  }];

$('#example').selectize({
  openOnFocus: true,
    options: optionList,
  labelField: "name",
  valueField: "id",
  sortField: "name",
  searchField: "name",
  closeAfterSelect: false,
    delimiter: ',',
    persist: false,
    maxItems: 15,
    create: function(input) {
        return {
            value: input,
            text: input
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.8.5/css/selectize.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.8.5/js/standalone/selectize.min.js"></script>



<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Selectize.js</label>
    <input type="text" class="" id="example" value="3,4,1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Teemu: I added both snippet code and jsFiddle. Please have a look